# The background JSP window disappears when a new JSP dialog is displayed

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsp, spring-mvc, struts

I have a JSP page (`first.jsp`) displayed. On the click of a button in this page, the server side code performs computation and requests for displaying a jJSP dialog(`dialog.jsp`). `dialog.jsp` should appear on top of `first.jsp`.

The `dialog.jsp` appears but when did does, the `first.jsp` disappears.
I tried including this in `first.jsp` and on page load, set this page to hidden:

```jsp
<jsp:include page="/WEB-INF/pages/dialog.jsp" /> 
$(function () {
 $("#dialog").modal('hide');    
});
```

But its not working! I am using Struts, Spring.

Answer (score 0):

First you need to set up the dialog on the div and not open it

```
$(function () {
 $("#dialog").dialog({modal: true, autoOpen: false});    
});
```

then open it on some event

```
$("#dialog").dialog("open");
```

Comment: What are you using? There's no error if you using jQuery UI.